# Query regarding joint distribution

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions, independence

I came across a question which I never seen before, I just need guidance to which specific topic in probability such questions belongs, so that I can have a look at them out of curiosity. Here's the question :

.

[image]

Comment: Are you sure the question mentioned Geometric Distribution? Geometric distribution is a discrete distribution. Or am I missing something quite obvious?

Comment: Well I found the question in such a format. "geometric probability" was mentioned which was not clear for me either

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would assume *geometric probability* means a measure proportional to a length of an interval.  So I would assume the intervals of length $1$ in $[-3,3]$ each have probability $\frac16$

So I think you have the joint density

```
   ω in interval    (X, Y)  Probability  
     -3 to -2       (0, 2)     1/6
     -2 to -1       (1, 1)     1/6 
     -1 to  0       (2, 0)     1/6 
      0 to  1       (2, 1)     1/6     
      1 to  2       (1, 2)     1/6  
      2 to  3       (0, 0)     1/6
```

$X$ and $Y$ are not independent: can you see why not?

Comment: Hi Thank you, I think you nailed it too. I think that's related to the fact that $P(x,y) $ $\ne$ $P(x)P(y)$ $\forall x,y$, as $P(x) = 1/3, P(y) = 1/3$ ?